# Netsuite oauth integration without Restlet

Tags: oauth, netsuite

I have accessed Netsuite in two ways.

**1.Using Credentials without Restlet**

**2.Using Oauth with Restlet**

But I searched code everywhere to connect Netsuite using Oauth without Restlet. i could not get anywhere.

Now i confused that whether Netsuite allowed to access using Oauth with Restlet only or not.

Help me to do further step. If there is a possibility to access Netsuite using Oauth without Restlet , Give me the code.
Thanks in Advance....

Comment: what do you mean by accessing NetSuite without RESTlet? you mean UI or Suitetalk ?

Comment: Suitetalk API Call(without writing script in Netsuite account)

Answer (score 0):

The code example is in the [SuiteAnswer Id 44710](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/44710) (You will need to login into NetSuite to read this)

The code example is in Java

You need to write:

1) logic to compute Hash  (you can use javax.crypto package)

2) logic to compute signature using #1 and netsuite account and token details

3) you need to add the signature in SOAP token passport header

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even though I logged in, I could not open your referral link, And I need PHP code also.

Comment: go to support tab and click suiteanswers, from there search for 44710. Sorry, I am not familiar with PHP syntax, the logic should be same anyways. Once, you are able to search for a library that is able to generate HMAC-SHA1, you should be good to go